# How to add cortege to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I read values to my dictionary and I want to add key: cortege.

```
for i in range(m):
    n1, n2, v = map(int, input().split())
    w = dict([v, (n1, n2)])
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `dict([(v, (n1, n2))])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What is wrong?" is a rather broad question, since you didn't mention what happens and what you expected to happen.

I'm guessing that you want to add a tuple to a dictionary, but you are creating a new one-element dictionary in each iteration of the loop. Perhaps something like this will do what you want:

```
w = {}
for i in range(m):
    n1, n2, v = map(int, input().split())
    w[v] = (n1, n2)
```

If not, please update your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your input format correctly, you can just zip n1, n2, v together and do dictionary comprehension:

```
n1s, n2s, vs = [1, 3, 5], [5, 8, 9], ["key1", "key2", "key3"]
print {v: (n1, n2) for n1, n2, v in zip(n1s, n2s, vs)}
>{'key3': (5, 9), 'key2': (3, 8), 'key1': (1, 5)}
```